# Registers not storing input

Tags: assembly, intel, 8051

I am taking inputs and storing them in registers R1 and R2. Then I perform comparision using `CJNE` command and if the input stored in R1 or R2 matches with the data in array, I would do something. But the problem is in the following code, sometimes R1 and R2 have data and sometimes they don't have. I have verfied it by debug mode and displaying the stuff inside them on Port. Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

The following program is written in `intel 8051 assembly` and assembled on `Keil uVision`

Kindly check the code:

```
ORG 00H

UserName: DB 12,13,14,0
Password: DB 15,125,240,0

MOV R0,#00h
mov R6,#04h
mov P1,#00h
mov p2,#00h

TakeUserName:

JB P2.1, TakePassword 

mov R1,P1 // storing username number in R1

SJMP TakeUserName

TakePassword:

JB P2.2, CheckUserName    

mov R2,P1 // storing password number in R2

 SJMP TakePassword


CheckUserName:

MOV DPTR,#UserName

Here1:

CLR A

MOVC A, @A+DPTR

INC DPTR

CJNE A, 01h,Here1   // compare A with data in R1

mov p2,#00h

Setb P2.0 

AJMP CheckPassword    

CheckPassword:

MOV DPTR,#Password

Here:

CLR A

MOVC A, @A+DPTR

INC DPTR

CJNE A, 02h,Here  

Setb P2.1 // setting of this bit shows password is successfully matched

AJMP Exit


End
```

Kindly guide me in finding the reason for this weird behavior.

Regards

Comment: You don't say anything about what you've connected to the ports or what you're inputting on them. I suggest that you step through your code in a debugger to find the problem. Just a brief note regarding the 8051 I/O ports if you're using external memory: "Port 0 and 2 may not be used as general purpose I/O when being used as the ADDR/DATA BUS for external memory during normal operation."  (see the "80C51 family hardware description" document)

Comment: I am simulating the code on Keil uVision at the moment